# Connection between arithmetic mean, geometric mean and sample variance

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be positive real numbers.
Arithmetic-geometric mean inequality tells us that:

$GM = \sqrt[n]{x_1 \dots x_n} \leq \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} = AM$

and that equality occurs iff $x_1 = \dots = x_n$. This condition can be restated as $\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - AM)^2 = 0$, i.e. sample variance of $x_1, \dots , x_n$ is zero.
I'm curious: are there any inequalities connecting arithmetic mean, geometric mean and sample variance?

This is my point: Difference between $AM$ and $GM$ gets larger as $x_1, \dots, x_n$ get further away from each other, i.e. when their sample variance is big.
Is there a way to account for the error in arithmetic-geometric mean inequality using sample variance?

Comment: What you ask for might be related to the concept of [majorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization). Hardy, Littlewood and Polya had already developed the theory to a very advanced level. If you are willing to pursue the study, you should probably check the book "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications".

Comment: Maybe these can help:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4417.pdf
and
http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4454

and references therein.

Answer (score 2):

Power mean inequality can be used to get bounds the difference between various means. Not exactly using variances, but you have
$$AM - GM \le \max_i x_i - \min_i x_i$$
Or if that's too large a bound, note
$$AM - GM \le AM - HM$$

If you want variances involved, try manipulating
$$\sqrt{\frac1n \sum x_i^2} - GM \ge AM-GM$$